# Material-ui horizontal menu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a horizontal menu component from material UI but it seems I'm unable to as all the list items are wrapped inside a `<div>`

The [docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/menu) show a vertical menu list

What works is if I remove all the outer `divs` inside the span, and remove the `display: block`style applied to the span.

```
<div style="padding: 8px 0px;">
   <div>
      <span tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: inherit; transform: translate(0px, 0px); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588); line-height: 16px; position: relative; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; background: none;">
         <div>
            <div style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 16px; position: relative;">
               <div>Inbox</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: inherit; transform: translate(0px, 0px); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588); line-height: 16px; position: relative; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; background: none;">
         <div>
            <div style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 16px; position: relative;">
               <div>Starred</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: inherit; transform: translate(0px, 0px); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588); line-height: 16px; position: relative; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; background: none;">
         <div>
            <div style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 16px; position: relative;">
               <div>Sent mail</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: inherit; transform: translate(0px, 0px); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588); line-height: 16px; position: relative; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; background: none;">
         <div>
            <div style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 16px; position: relative;">
               <div>Drafts</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: inherit; transform: translate(0px, 0px); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588); line-height: 16px; position: relative; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; background: none;">
         <div>
            <div style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 16px; position: relative;">
               <div>Inbox</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the CSS className on the Menu that styles its immediate DIV children with  "display: inline-block"

Working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d980vcon/2/

in CSS:

```
.horiz-menu > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

In JSX:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Menu className="horiz-menu">
        <MenuItem primaryText="Home"/>
        <MenuItem primaryText="Test Menu 1" />
        <MenuItem primaryText="Test Menu 2" />
        <MenuItem primaryText="About" />
      </Menu>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex` as part of your css, which in your menu you can access using the attribute `className="myStyle"` for styling like so:

```
.myStyle {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    overflow: 'hidden'
}
```

as part of your css.

Comment: @chefcurry7 did the above provide the answer to your question?